# When Apk file is added manually, It crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

When I run my project in Android Studio, it just works fine on device when usb is connected. However, when I extract the apk and install it manually to device, my second activity crashes. What might be the reason?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.figengungor.gazeteler"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile project(':sweetalert')
```

Logcat:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.figengungor.gazeteler, PID: 8879
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at a.b.b.l.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.b.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.c.di.b(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.c.di.a(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.c.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.figengungor.gazeteler.c.d.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.figengungor.gazeteler.activities.f.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.figengungor.gazeteler.activities.f.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
            at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
            at a.b.b.k.d(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.b.k.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.b.l.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.b.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.c.di.b(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.c.di.a(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.c.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at a.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.figengungor.gazeteler.c.d.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.figengungor.gazeteler.activities.f.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.figengungor.gazeteler.activities.f.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: logcat will be helpful

Comment: Did you apply proguard ?

Comment: I added my build.gradle

Comment: @jimpanzer how can I access logcat when I add apk manually and run it.

Comment: install the app connect your phone to PC open your IDE choose logcat run the app and then filter out logcat results pertaining to your app alone. Then post the logcat here.

Comment: @Aadi, I added my logcat.

Comment: Disable proguard in build.gradle, minfyEnabled=false.
Then see if the same crash repeats

Comment: Thank you, it doesnt crash now. Do you know why can't I use proguard?

Comment: Unless you ignore required part of your project from obfuscation, your application is prone to crash. basically you need to manually specify some classes to be excluded from proguard.

Are you using any library?

Comment: See, for example,
if you read here, https://github.com/square/picasso
in proguard you are suppoesed to add , -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

Similarly for all the libraries you use, find out what should be added to proguard ignore list.